# How to avoid over ride of labels which are added to cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 33)];
    dataLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(105, 0, 320, 33)];
    timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dataLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dataLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:dataLabel];

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        if([storedDataArray count]>0)
        {
            timeLabel.text = currenttime;
            dataLabel.text = textView1.text;
        }
        return cell; //returns empty cell if there is no data in the data base
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
            timeLabel.text = currenttime;
            dataLabel.text = textView2.text;
        return cell;
    }
```

I have a table view 
- i want to display my textlabel on left side, just beside detailTextlabel.

- actually when i use textLabel.text, DetailTextLabel.Text and alignments,
  they displayed but not at the position i want.
- so i tried to use own labels..
- but they get overwritten.
- since we did not (it's not possible to) change the possition & the frame size of the cell textlabel, detailTextLabel, i added 2 labels with a frame size that i want.
- - but when we entered text in text views and return back to table view.. the labels get overwritten..

what to do..

- is there any alternate to fixed the frame size of my text label
- or to avoid overwriting of our labels

Comment: can you explain more about what you are trying to do ?

Comment: i need to display my textlabele on most left side, just beside it detailTextlabel.

actually when i use textLabel.text, DetailTextLabel.Text and allignments..
the are displayed but in proper position wat i want.
so i use own labels..

but they are over write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Custom UITableViewCell instead. You can align and place labels easily using custom tabe cells.

This link will be helpful. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

look at the customizing section in the document.

Answer (score 0):

use this code it will work perfectly

```
 if (cell== nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuNameCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"---------new cell agin");   
}
   else
{
    NSArray *arrayView = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for (UIView *vTemp in arrayView)
    {
        [vTemp removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSLog(@"---No New Cell hiiii");

    // Setting Tag To UIButton
    _checkButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    _cancelButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
}
```

add else part only